# Visualising data with three independent variables

Tags: data-visualization

I am trying to visualise a data set with three independent variables (two categories and a time scale) and one dependent variable (count). What would be the best way to show this data?

Comment: This could be a really fun post if you provide some toy data to play with, and to make the answers more concrete and comparable.

Comment: I agree with antoni. Please provide some example data then we can walk you through the principles of multivariate plotting etc

Answer (score 2):

One way that I've found useful is to display (quasi) continuous variables (count, time) on an x,y scatter plot, then distinguish the categorical variables by shapes and colors. So if one of your categorical variables has 2 levels and the other 3, use squares versus circles for the first and three different colors for the second. How well this works, of course, will depend on your data and what you wish most to visualize.